# tensorflow lite on arduino nano 33 BLE : Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'EXPAND_DIMS' version '1'

Tags: python, arduino, tensorflow-lite, converters

I used Tensorflow lite 2.1.1-ALPHA-PRECOMPILED for arduino nano 33 ble with headers

Import

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
```

Model Definition

```
def get_model(n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs): 
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())  
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')) 
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
    # fit network
    return model
```

model = get_model(128, 6, num_class=4)

Model Summary

[image]

TF Lite Converter Work but add expandsdims operation

```
# Convert the model to the TensorFlow Lite format without quantization

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
def representative_dataset():
    for _, samp in enumerate(trainX):
        yield [samp.astype(np.float32).reshape(1, 128, 6)]
    # Set the optimization flag.
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    # Enforce integer only quantization
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
    # Provide a representative dataset to ensure we quantize correctly.
    converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
    model_tflite = converter.convert()

   # Save the model to disk
   open('default_tf/model0_1.tflite', "wb").write(model_tflite)
```

When i check tflite structure via netron i found that the exapandsDims operation is included as shown in the following image
[image]

I already try to include

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
```

to my sketch But did not resolve the problem and io also tried  to include

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/kernels/micro_ops.h"
static tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<1> micro_op_resolver;
void setup(){
  micro_op_resolver.AddExpandDims();
}
```

in this case i get a error:

```
   micro_op_resolver.AddExpandDims();
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
exit status 1
'class tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<1>' has no member named 'AddExpandDims'
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem to downgrade the python version of tensorflow from 2.3.0 to 2.1.1 where i trained the model, in 2.1.1 for convert the model intessorflow-lite use reshape ops where its replaced in 2.3.0 with exapandsdims ops.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem but found a solution that avoids downgrading Tensorflow (so we can use the latest Tensorflow 2.4.1). The Tensorflow 1D operations, e.g., `Conv1D`, are specialized versions of their higher order counterparts, e.g., `Conv2D`. Therefore, you can "upgrade" your 1D operations without sacrificing accuracy. The Tensorflow Lite Converter does the same thing but replaces the `Conv1D` with `Conv2D` AND an additional `ExpandDims` layer before that - hence the problem.

Here is the procedure:

1. Adjust the `input_shape` for your network by adding another dimension of size 1, e.g., `input_shape=(3,3,1)` instead of `input_shape=(3,3)`
2. Replace the 1D operations with their 2D counterpart (`Conv1D` to `Conv2D`, `MaxPooling1D` to `MaxPooling2D`)
3. Adjust the `kernel_size` for your `Conv2D` layers, e.g., `kernel_size=(3,1)` instead of `kernel_size=3`
4. Adjust the `pool_size` for the pooling layers (such as `MaxPooling2D` or `GlobalAveragePooling2D`), e.g., `pool_size=(2,1)` instead of `pool_size=2`
5. Retrain the network
6. Convert your model to Tensorflow Lite Micro

**Your model after conversion**

```
def get_model(n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs): 
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,1), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5,1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1)))
    model.add(Flatten())  
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')) 
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
    # fit network
    return model
```

**Downsides**

- You have to adjust your training data to account for the extra dimension
- You have to adjust the input data for your network whenever you run inference
- You have to retrain your network

We tried to avoid the adjustments of our training data and input data for inference by adding a `Reshape` layer right after the `Input` layer of your model. Unfortunately, this lead to another problem after pruning, int8 quantitating, and converting our model to Tensorflow Lite Micro. Without the reshaping everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Arduino IDE, was able to install the latest version of tflite micro and it resolved all issues https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro-arduino-examples